# Wordpress Contact Form -7 and Pardot integration

Tags: wordpress, pardot

I am new to WordPress. I am working on integrating WordPress form data to Pardot. I have a Contact Form 7 (CF-7) on my website which is mapped to submit the data to Pardot.
I followed this link to integrate the CF-7 form with the Salesforce Pardot. https://www.digitalmenta.com/en/inbound-marketing/how-to-integrate-pardot-forms-into-wordpress/
I used the #4 method: Connection between Contact Form 7 and Pardot Form Handlers

Now I don’t see any network call happening when I submit data and at the same time I don’t see any data posting in Pardot. Can anyone help me with this is the issue of how to debug.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an existing form integration in Wordpress, I highly recommend using Pardot's native Wordpress plugin and `Pardot forms` rather than a `form handler`.

The reason is that an embedded Pardot form will post data directly and automatically, while a form handler posts to Pardot as a secondary endpoint (not to mention that there are far more limited reporting and automation capabilities with the latter as well).  Feel free to reach out for more information.